# Loosing video quality when merging files

Tags: ffmpeg

Creating a video from 2 videos (each video is about 15MB, with good quality), merging them side by side is causing loosing the videos quality and creating a movie with the size of 1MB.

i made a command that takes 2 movies, placing them side by side and merging them to one movie.

```
ffmpeg -threads 11 -i 1.mp4 -i 2.mp4 -i logo.png -filter_complex [0:v]pad=width=iw+20:height=ih+20:x=10:y=10:color=black[a];[1:v]pad=width=iw+20:height=ih+20:x=10:y=10:color=black[b];
nullsrc=size=1280x960[base];[a]setpts=PTS-STARTPTS,scale=640x960[left];[b]setpts=PTS-STARTPTS,scale=640x960[right];[base][left]overlay=shortest=1[tmp1];[tmp1][right]overlay=640:0[video];[0:a]apad[apa];[1:a]apad[apa1];[apa][apa1]amix=inputs=2:duration=longest[audio];[2:v]scale=120:44[ovrl];[video][ovrl]overlay=20:45[videoandlogo] -map [videoandlogo] -map [audio] -t 25 output.mp4
```

why is the command reduce the quality and creating only a 1MB file?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> why is the command reduce the quality and creating only a 1MB file?

Because nowhere are you specifying a quality, or a bit rate, so its using ffmpeg defaults.

use `-cfr <number>` to specify a quality e.g. `-crf 23`

or user `-b <number>` to specify a bit rate/target file size e.g. `-b 2000k` for 2Mbps

Comment: Thanks a lot. works (i specify the target file size).

Comment: @S.T Please accept the answer it the solution worked.